# How to use Python files spread out over many folders, or: how to organize a project

Tags: python

I am looking to make my project fulfill the guidelines described here: http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/. I currently have the following directories:

```
src/
test/
doc/
```

I would really like to organize my `src/` file as follows:

```
src/
   similar_files/
   other_files/
   helpers/
   etc
```

However, I'm not familiar with how I could have my modules and classes interact the same way, i.e. if some module in one folder needs access to one in another folder. Is this a bad way to organize my project? If not, how can I accomplish what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to read the tutorial.. [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)! :D

Section [6.4.2](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) also contains the references that would assist you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick and informative answer. Have an upvote until I am allowed to mark you as an answer!